# Something wrong with tag view in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, russian-stackoverflow

Android app returns old questions by tag for Stack Overflow in Russian. E.g. for tag [c++]:

> [image: Android app]

Recently active post is 16 hours ago.

But actually recently active post (via web) is 4 minutes:

> [image: Mobile web]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1710300506712)

Comment: No repro (on any site) on the iOS app (which should be the same if it was an API issue)

Comment: @Cai yep. Just check for iOS too, it works fine. Relevant only for the Android app.

Comment: @Elias bug suggested by you shows same posts but with different dates. In my case there are different posts at all.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on English StackOverflow when using the "Newest" filter and searching by tags. Alexolut's answer suggests the problem was fixed on Sept 11, but I've been having the issue since Sept 15 or 16. Questions after that date are not loading, only questions before that date

Comment: @RemyLebeau yep. Seems it happened again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fixed now. Probably the root of problem has been fixed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300720/339911

But I still don't understand why it affected only Android app and not iOS app.

**Update**

Seems it happened again as Remy said on his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300679/something-wrong-with-tag-view-in-the-android-app#comment978548_300679).