# Search for new questions returns yesterday and older posts on most Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Using search for new questions returns yesterday's and older posts for many sites. Tested for localized Stack Overflow...

- [in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq)
- [in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq)
- [in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq)
- [in Japanese](https://jp.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq)

and other sites such as [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq), [Super User](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq), etc.

English Stack Overflow [works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq). So does [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq)

Possibly related to my previous bug report: [Something wrong with tag view in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300679/339911)

**Seems this happens again. Now for SO and MSE too.**

Comment: This is not just localized sites but "everyone except en-SO". See: [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq), [Super User](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq).

Comment: @Michelle feel free to edit this post according new information. Just checked: it works for [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq).

Comment: Okay, I suggested an edit expanding it to "many sites" without claiming an exhaustive list. Meta.SE is special in many ways, essentially a development branch, so I'm not surprised it doesn't have the same bug.

Comment: My bet is on Nick for breaking it: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/906133210156892160

Comment: @rene so how long will re-reindexing take? Hopefully less than 6-8 weeks...

Comment: I'm having this problem on English StackOverflow in the Android app. Questions after Sept 15 or so are not loading. The website works fine, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as much as I'd like to blame Nick, it's not *just* his fault. In preparation for our upgrade to Elastic v2.4.6 (on our way to v5.5.2) we started re-indexing all sites in the network on Friday and I kicked off Stack Overflow on Saturday morning. Stack Overflow is a pretty large site to index (46m documents) and it takes about 3 hours at full speed. Indexing that many documents while serving live search traffic hurts the cluster so we decided to introduce an abort function in case we needed to stop it in a hurry.

But... that new functionality had a bug and the deltas that run to keep the indexes in sync with their sites didn't run. I've now fixed the bug and pushed to production. Indexes are catching up now so all should be well in the next hour or two.

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: But some fault is still Nick's, right?