# Android app not in sync with website

Tags: bug, android-app

Over the past day or so, I've been noticing that the Android app is not loading new questions anymore. Filtering on specific tags shows questions that are a couple of days old. But going to the website and filtering on the same tags shows newer questions have been posted.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SAMSUNG-SM-G935A
- OS Version: 7.0 (G935AUCS4BQH1)

Comment: Related (possible duplicate? although that says it was fixed): [Something wrong with tag view in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300679/307988)

Comment: Possibly, but that says the issue was fixed on Sept 11, but my issue didn't start happening until like Sept 15 or 16

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was fixed or at least looked so, but now happened again and affects enSO too (my report didn't affect enSO).

Comment: Seems fixed again (?) Related [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300969/339911).

Comment: @alexolut yes, it is working now

Comment: Will wait for a new round :)