# Advanced search API not returning results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, api

When you set the minimum time to 2017-09-16 there aren't any results returned:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&min=1505520000&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

Comment: Not familiar with API, but common sense says you must put something to search for in order for search to return results.

Comment: If you turn the time-stamp to the previous day it works https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&min=1505433600&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

Comment: hmm... well so probably bug indeed, something hasn't been indexed properly.

Answer (score 5):

Oh dear. We moved over to a new set of Elastic code on Friday afternoon and, well, we forgot to deploy the API project to production. That means it was running against an old Elastic index that hasn't been updated since Friday.

I just pushed the button to deploy the project and your API request now returns results.

Sorry about that, thanks for letting us know!

Comment: I thought changes on a Friday afternoon always worked without issues... :)

Comment: Well, in fairness, the changes have been running side-by-side for a couple of weeks and serving SO's traffic since Wednesday, we just deleted a bunch of old code on Friday  :p

Comment: I'm not making excuses, honest!