# Q field of search/advanced in Stack Exchange API now behaving strangely

Tags: bug, search, api

As the title suggests, as of this week the Q field of the /search/advanced API endpoint is behaving strangely.  Last week entering the text "Hello World" in the Q field would return many articles, however as of today no articles are returned.

You can view an example here: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=hello%20world&site=stackoverflow

Is there any chance this could be fixed? Our application depends on users being able to enter freeform text in the Q field to perform searches.

Thank you

Edit:

Searching for a single word that is also a tag like "java" seems to work
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=java&site=stackoverflow

Comment: I noticed this while investigating [this related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300969/advanced-search-api-not-returning-results).  Perhaps it's not completely fixed.

Comment: Agreed, it might be that certain things still haven't been properly indexed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced search API not returning results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300969/advanced-search-api-not-returning-results)